# Как плотно друг к другу расположить элементы?

Tags: visio

При совмещении двух элементов не происходит плотное соединение.
Они либо соединяются внахлёст либо не дотягиваются чуть-чуть.
Т.е. где-то как-то установился шаг.. Перетаскивания объекта

Почему так происходит и как это можно исправить?
Т.е. чтобы элементы прилегали к друг-другу вплотную.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [кросс-пост](http://visio.getbb.ru/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=1084) с серией советов на этот вопрос. К сожалению топик-стартер не ответил помогли ли ему эти советы